# showmodaldialogue

Tags: javascript, showmodaldialog

I used a showmodal dialog window from which I send a request to back end, it was working fine and when I checked again it showed "object doesn't support this property or method" .it happens suddenly and am sure i didnt do any change in the code!!

```
var PasswordAlert=null;
PasswordAlert=window.showModalDialog(htmlreq,"","dialogWidth:400px;dialogHeight:148px;edge:sunken;scroll:no;status:no;modal=yes");
```

this is the code where i get error, while calling showModalDialog.

Comment: you have to put the htmlreq inside quotation mark. and check, may be in your browser popup dialog is blocked.

Comment: what browser did you use? what is `htmlreq`? it has to be URL.

Comment: htmlreq is -(https://localhost:3124/16911-CHG-PASSWORD.php?usrname=MANOJ&usrpasswd=mANOJ@123&newpasswd=mAN@123)

Comment: @nareshkumar htmlreq is a variable so giving inside quotes didnt work, and pop-up is not blocked also..it was working good but suddenly am getting this error

Comment: i tested in my machine. the alert box is coming. just remove all cookie and browser cache and check it may help.

Comment: @nareshkumar no it didnt help..do u think it might be cause of the htmlreq string length causes the problem?

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan am using IE6 and also tested in IE8 i got same error .irony is it was working fine, suddenly getting this error.and the page from where i call this modaldialogue is itself a modaldialogue(this is fine) but the another one creates this issue

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan IE6 support should also be there thats why i use it! the error occur in mainwindow(which is a modal dialogue itself) when i tried debugging, it showed, the object doesn't support this property or method when calling showmodaldialogue.do you think the length of the html string cause problem??

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan with google.com it works fine but my doubt is whether the length of the url matters?? and there is listening port and everything is fine!

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan Hi, Thanks for your help but in my case passing it as dialog argument doesn't work out,cuz i have to use the same page as modaldialog again to where i pass it as arg..and about URL it's a request sent to the Back end so if i open it separately its showing nothing..is it with length of the url which makes the problem??

Answer (score 0):

IE6 - you must be kidding)) Didn't expect that somebody used it for far).

Is any software listening to the 3124 port? Are you sure it is runnig when you try?

What happens if go to that url directly(past it directly into browser address line)?

Just tried to run this code from console - it worked in IE6+

```
var PasswordAlert=null;
PasswordAlert=window.showModalDialog('https://google.com',"","dialogWidth:400px;dialogHeight:148px;edge:sunken;scroll:no;status:no;modal=yes");
```

If it works - something wrong with your URL or page you are tring to open.

Does that code work in any of adequate browsers(Chrome, FF)? For me - does.

Where does error occur: in main window or in dialog? Also browser has to show you line where error accurs and say which one object doesn't have property.

There are lot of questions you can ask yourself.

**UPD:**

What happens if you open URL directly?

Try to open in dialog for URL without query string and pass it as second `window.showModalDialog` function parameter. Then passed data will be accessible from dialog via `window.dialogArguments` property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The popup blocker turned on in IE?